# Delete files older than a specific file modified date

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with .bak and .log files.

I want to delete .bak files older than 7 days but keep last 4 and I do it with 
forfiles skip.

Then I want to delete all .log files older than the modified date of the last remaing .bak file and here is where I have the problem.how Can I find the moddate of the older .bak file and then compare with it on the delete .log ?

```
pushd "C:\temp2"
for %%X in (bak) do (
  set "skip=1"
  for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw *.%%X') do (
    if defined skip forfiles /d -1 /m "%%F" >nul 2>nul && set "skip="
    if not defined skip del "%%F" 
  )
) 

for %%a in ("C:\temp2\*.bak" /O:-D ) do set FileDate=%%~ta
forfiles /P "C:\temp2\*.log" /S /D -%FileDate%  "cmd /C del @file"
```

Comment: ½ way down the page you'll find a thing I wrote 10 years ago about making custom disk cleanup handlers. Disk Cleanup run automatically on your computer. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/cleanmgr-command-line-switches/0a8fc705-b233-40cc-bfa2-269216767263?messageId=46cf3a43-9a43-4b62-9fd1-5928e74b64ea&page=1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example for you, which uses [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) instead of the less efficient [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles) command.

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "C:\temp2" 2>Nul || Exit /B
If Not Exist *.bak Exit /B
Set "RO=/NS /NJS /NJH /NDL /NC"
Set "DM="
For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=1,2*" %%A In (
    'RoboCopy . $tmp *.bak /TS %RO% /MINAGE:7 /L ^| Sort /R'
) Do If Not Defined DM (Set "DM=%%A") Else Del "%%C"
If Not Exist *.log Exit /B
If Not Defined DM (For /F "Tokens=1,2*" %%A In (
    'RoboCopy . $tmp *.bak /TS %RO% /L ^| Sort /R') Do Set "DM=%%A")
If Defined DM (RoboCopy . $tmp *.log %RO% /MOV /MINAGE:%DM:/=% > Nul
    RD /S /Q $tmp 2> Nul)
```

*The code uses then removes a temporary directory in the source directory, `C:\temp2`, named `$tmp`. If you are likely to have a directory already in that location with that name, you can change the name on lines `12` and `13` to something less likely.*